# Avoiding Safari's repeated requests for IndexedDB permission beyond 50 MB

Tags: safari, indexeddb

I'm trying to get Safari to run a series of tests ([web-platform-tests](https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests)) served from my local machine. The tests create a large amount of data in IndexedDB for which Safari requires permission (requests are for larger than 50 MB) but this gets too cumbersome to approve permission each time when cycling through hundreds of tests.

In `Preferences->Privacy->Cookies and website data->Manage Website Data...`, there is an entry, "Local documents on your computer (Databases)" apparently indicating the presence of this data, but it does not provide any configuration options, nor does `Preferences->Privacy->Cookies and website data->Always allow` work to avoid the prompting.

Is there any other config which can allow me to get around the need for manual permission? (I'm asking here instead of superuser, as I don't know if there might also be an API which can persist overcoming the limit as well.)

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/issues/5671 is related to automating things that need permission prompts